# Rewrite to remove url - kohana 3.2 and .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3.2

My installation of Kohana 3.2 works well. The site is navigable and also the CRUD functions works. He is in the example address: www.site.com.br/folder/.

At .Htacess I have

```
     # Turn on URL rewriting
     RewriteEngine On

     # Installation directory ()
     RewriteBase /folder/

     # Protect hidden files from being viewed
    Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    /Files>

     # Protect application and system files from being viewed
     RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

     # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
     RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

When I write the complete url `www.site.com.br/folder/` url it work.

But now the server is pointing to the root and I need to be like `www.site.com.br`, in other works, remove the `folder/`.

I tried some options but the Kohana stop working:

`RewriteRule .* folder/index.php/$0 [PT]` or
`RewriteRule ^folder/(.*).* index.php/$0 [PT]`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove the `RewriteBase` from the HyperText Access script. Then, the URI's will be parsed correctly within Kohana.